# NSDictionary countForKey

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nsdictionary

So is there a countForKey or something similar to that for NSDictionary?  I do know that there is a count method but is there something like countForKey or do I have to make a NSDictionary category for it?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Even though `[dictionary count]` seems like the easiest approach, you could get the array of keys from the dictionary and then retrieve the array count, so:

```
NSUInteger keyCount = [dictionary count];
```

would return the same as:

```
NSUInteger keyCount = [[dictionary allKeys] count];
```

**EDIT:**
With the additional information you provided in the comment, if you want to find out how many 'keys' (although your true requirement still isn't that clear):

```
NSUInteger keyCountForObject = [[dictionary allKeysForObject:object] count];
```

Comment: I know that there is a count method in NSDictionary, but I want the dictionary to return the number of object that has the key, for example, "Name"

Comment: oh, that's much better.  Thanks.

Comment: That's the opposite relationship--that's the number of keys associated with the object, not the number of objects associated with the key. They're not the same thing.

Answer (score 3):

Dictionaries represent a set of 1:1 relationships. Every key represents just one object. So this hypothetical `-countForKey:` would always return 0 if the key-value pair were not represented in the dictionary, and 1 if it were. You can never have a key in a dictionary representing two or more objects.

Comment: I recognize the relationship and was thoughtful in my response. Truth be told, you can have multiple keys point to the same object. I thought this was tAP's intent although the requirement still seems a little fuzzy.

Comment: I know multiple keys can point to the same object. I'm saying the opposite relationship does not hold, as that seems to be what the original question was about.